# Difference between TOA and SR in Landsat sensors

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, landsat-8

I am looking at long-term mangrove forest change (1990-2020) in Indonesia using Landsat satellites. These are the years and sensors I have chosen:

2020- Landsat 8 T1 SR // 2010- Landsat 5 TM T1 TOA // 2000- Landsat 7 T1 SR // 1990-  Landsat 5 T1 TOA

Since I am using TOA and SR in various years, will there will be any inconsistency in my analysis. And if yes, what can I do to make sure every image composite is of the same type?

Comment: Since you are looking at multiple time periods, you will need to convert everything to SR.

Comment: @Aaron Thank you. Could you have materials to explain how to convert TOA into SR?

Comment: Why not use precomputed SR products? More details: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/landsat#surface-reflectance

Comment: Yeah it took me a second, but yea I figured I could just use the SR products.

Comment: Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are working with time-series data, you will want to make sure all your imagery is corrected to surface reflectance (SR). Google Earth Engine makes precomputed SR Landsat products available: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog.

You should use these precomputed SR products for your analysis.